# change sort order of modelchoicefield django

Tags: django-forms

how can I change the order of the values in the ModelChoiceField billing_company?

models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
```

forms.py

```
billing_company = forms.ModelChoiceField(Company.objects, required=True)
```

Thanks for your help.
Tom

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`ModelChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield) takes a QuerySet as its first parameter, so you should be able to pass an ordered set:

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(Company.objects.order_by('-pk'), required=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort it in the template, you can manually render the form and iterate over the options and sort them using the [`dictsort`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort) templatetag (or any other templatetag that sorts according to what you like), e.g.

```
{% for value, option in form.fields.billing_company.choices|dictsort:1 %}
    <option value="{{ value }}">{{ option }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```